# javascript alert box show html currency symbol

Tags: javascript

How to show html currency symbol in javascript alert box. I am showing the message where currency and price both are dynamic so i need to get currency from html codes. Please provide me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p id="eu">&euro;</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var txt = document.getElementById("eu").textContent || document.getElementById("eu").innerText;

alert(txt);
</script>
```

**NOTE:** [HERE](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) you can find html entities

Comment: `.textContent`, please... no need to give people an XSS vector ;)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on *which* currency sign you want. The generic ¤ CURRENCY SIGN is `\xA4`...

Use `\xA3` to represent `£`, `\u20AC` to represent `€`, and for more just use the handy tool called Character Map.

[image: charmap]